# Calculate Growth rate between two dates in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

This is the table Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `profit_log` (
  `market_id` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `total_purchase` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `total_profit` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `company_profit` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `tid` bigint(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
--
-- Indexes for table `profit_log`
--
ALTER TABLE `profit_log`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`tid`);
```

I'm calculating the accumulative purchase between dates using following query:

```
SELECT `market_id`,
    SUM(`total_purchase`) as acc_purchase,
    SUM(`total_profit`) as acc_profit,
    SUM(`company_profit`) as acc_company_profit
FROM `profit_log`
WHERE `date` >= '2016-01-01'
AND `date` < ('2016-01-20' + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
AND `market_id` IN (1,2,5,8,22)
GROUP BY `market_id`
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to calculate growth rate for each `market_id` in this query ?.

```
growth rate = ((total_purchase as top where date = '2016-01-20')-(total_purchase as bottom where date = '2016-01-01')/bottom) * 100
```

is it possible to do that all in one query or it needs to be calculated in separate query ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT o.`market_id`,
    SUM(o.`total_purchase`) as acc_purchase,
    SUM(o.`total_profit`) as acc_profit,
    SUM(o.`company_profit`) as acc_company_profit,

    (SELECT total_purchase FROM profit_log as i WHERE o.market_id = i.market_id AND i.`date` = '2016-01-01')
        /
    (SELECT total_purchase FROM profit_log as i WHERE o.market_id = i.market_id AND i.`date` = '2016-01-20')
        as growth_rate,

FROM `profit_log` as o
WHERE `date` >= '2016-01-01'
AND `date` < ('2016-01-20' + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
AND `market_id` IN (1,2,5,8,22)
GROUP BY `market_id`
```